# Get HttpMessageNotReadableException Exception when using Spring - RestTemplate

Tags: java, xml, spring, resttemplate

I'm using springframework -RestTemplate,
in order to make get request , and convert the xml response to java object.
After the operation : RestTemplate.exchange,
I got the following exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Order] from
```

The response from the client in XML, and I added it to the headers:

```
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

So why it's trying to parse the response as JSON?
and how can I resolve it?

Thanks!!

Comment: You probably do not have the MessageConverter required for xml to object conversion

Comment: Hi ,
I tried to add :
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
But still getting this exception. Which messeageConverter should I use?

Thanks

Comment: Did you also add Jackson2 to your classpath?

Comment: I'm using mvn and add dependency for :
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause is you are getting some XML which does not conform to the deserialization rules defined in your model (or maybe it is malformed XML).

Other possible cause is your `RestTemplate` missing a message converter capable of dealing with XML conversion. By default, Spring Boot configures a `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`, but only if you have JAXB2 in your classpath, so you should check this dependency is available to your project.

You can print which message converters are registered in your `RestTemplate`, and which media types they accept, with the following code:

```
for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : restTemplate.getMessageConverters()) {
    System.out.println("Converter: " + converter.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", supports: "
                + converter.getSupportedMediaTypes().toString());
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks ,
I print the converters , and  Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter is one of them.
But i'm still getting this exception.
There is way to hint spring which converter to use?

Comment: If you have a message converter which supports XML format, can you verify the server is sending the proper content-type header? something like `application/xml`, and not `text/plain` or `text/html`.